# Separate sentences in a content and then use Stanford dependency parser

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

By using this code I can get the whole text dependency:

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tree import Tree
stanford_models = 'E:\stanford-parser\stanford-parser-3.7.0-models.jar'
stanford_jar = 'E:\stanford-parser\stanford-parser.jar'
st = StanfordDependencyParser(stanford_models, stanford_jar, encoding='utf-8')
text = 'She is doing phd. She is studying civil engineering.'
result = st.raw_parse(text)
dep = result.__next__()
list(dep.triples())
```

and the output is :

```
[(('doing', 'VBG'), 'nsubj', ('She', 'PRP')),
 (('doing', 'VBG'), 'aux', ('is', 'VBZ')),
 (('doing', 'VBG'), 'dobj', ('phd', 'NNP')),
 (('phd', 'NNP'), 'acl:relcl', ('studying', 'VBG')),
 (('studying', 'VBG'), 'nsubj', ('She', 'PRP')),
 (('studying', 'VBG'), 'aux', ('is', 'VBZ')),
 (('studying', 'VBG'), 'dobj', ('engineering', 'NN')),
 (('engineering', 'NN'), 'amod', ('civil', 'JJ'))]
```

My question is how can I modify this code to get this result separately for each sentence? The desire output can be something like this :

```
[(('doing', 'VBG'), 'nsubj', ('She', 'PRP')),
     (('doing', 'VBG'), 'aux', ('is', 'VBZ')),
     (('doing', 'VBG'), 'dobj', ('phd', 'NNP'))] ,  [(('studying', 'VBG'), 'nsubj', ('She', 'PRP')),
     (('studying', 'VBG'), 'aux', ('is', 'VBZ')),
     (('studying', 'VBG'), 'dobj', ('engineering', 'NN')),
     (('engineering', 'NN'), 'amod', ('civil', 'JJ'))]
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but could you not split the text on the periods? `for sentence in text.split(".")`

Comment: No this one doesn't work.

Comment: Split text into sentences with the `nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize()` method.